# Using RegEx to change the date with string inbuilt function in java

Tags: java, json

I have a below code where I need to replace all "buyDate:YYYY-mm-dd" to current date using String.replaceAll method. Any suggestion how I can update date for only buyDate field, since I have some other date field so I cannot directly perform replace operation.

`String str = content .replace("yyyy-mm-dd", LocalDate.now().toString());`

I am using loading below data to string object which is stored in json file.

Json file:

````
    "id": 123,
    "test": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "string"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "manufactureDate":"2018-12-12"
            "product": {
                "id": "12345",
                "buyDate": "2019-04-15",
            },
            "Moreitems": [
                {
                    "id": "qwerty123",
                    "manufactureDate":"2018-12-12"
                    "product": {
                        "id": "qwerty345",
                        "buydate": "2019-04-15",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: `replaceAll` takes a regular expression but isn't it best to decode the json and then change the data properly before encoding it back?

Comment: But to decode the json, we need Mapper classes however here unfortunately the json which we are referring is dynamic. Is there a way to decode and update? I am new to java and would be great if you share some logic/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression to match the search pattern.
You can learn more about how to write regular expressions at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Briefly:

- `\s` matches a white space character
- `\d` matches a digit
- `*` means match the preceding token 0 or more times
- `{4}` means match the preceding token exactly 4 times

The regular expression that matches a date is: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`.
It means match four digits followed by dash then two digits then a dash then two digits.

Of course you need to escape the back-slack when you are writing a string literal in java. You also need to escape the double quotes.

```
String result = content.replaceAll("(\"buyDate\"\\s*:\\s*\"(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})\")", "\"buyDate\":" + LocalDate.now().toString() + "\"");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However one more small doubt, if we have offetDateTime object instead of Date object how we can ignore string after the date. For Ex: if ```"buyDate":"2019-04-09T13:21:00.866Z"``` is this so how can we ignore string after 09 from this date to make replaceAll work for all offsetDateTime object.

Comment: Easy. Modify oroginal Regexp by adding "(T.*Z)?":

("buyDate"\s*:\s*"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(T.*Z)?)")

This will process both simple date and date-time

Comment: But while replacing to current date, it seems that it is missing starting double quote:"buyDate":2020-06-21T20:43:53.266"......Before 2020 double quote is missing

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to do it, is use a JSON serializer/deserializer like GSON or Jackson to deserialize the data into java classes, do the changes there then serialize them back.
Even if you add the field name in your search string, the replaceAll() won't respect the hierarchical structure, so you may end up replacing things you don't want to.

To use those deserializers, you need to create classes such as

```
class Product{
  public int id;
  public string buyDate;
}

class Item{
  public int id;
  public string manufactureDate;
  public Product product;
}

class Test{
  public int id;
  public string name;
}

class Inventory{
   public int id;
   public Test test;
   public List<Item> items;
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Inventory inventory = gson.fromJson(jsonFileContents, Inventory.class);
inventory.items.get(0).manufactureDate = "2020-01-01";
String jsonString = gson.toJson(inventory);
```

Comment: understood, but in my case I have a json which has object inside same object. Hence when I used Jackson API it is only fetching 1st level object as it is shown above, only items object was getting deserialized, inside items Array it consists MoreItems array and for this array I am getting below error.

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "moreItems"```

Comment: I thought that was a typing error, is that valid JSON?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same Json to run my integration test using Rest-assured.